# Create a character variable with data.frame function

Tags: r, class, dataframe, char

Using the `data.frame` function in R, I am creating an example dataset. However, the vectors with strings are converted to a **factor** column.

How can I make vectors with strings (e.g. `var1`) become **character** column in my data set?

**Current Code**

```
df = data.frame(var1 = c("1","2","3","4"), 
                var2 = c(1,2,3,4))
```

**Resulting Output**

As shown below, `var1` is a factor. I need `var1` it to have the `chr` class.

```
> str(df)

'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
$ var1 : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 2 3 4
$ var2 : num  1 2 3 4
```

**Trouble-shooting**

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/7983039), I tried adding `as.character`, but `var1` remains a factor.

```
df = data.frame(var1 = as.character(c("1","2","3","4")), 
                var2 = c(1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: See `?data.frame`. What you're looking for is `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Comment: Using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` did work. I had previously tried this, but it created a column of "FALSE". So I must have made a mistake.

Comment: You probably put quotes around FALSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringsAsFactors` is your friend. Namely:

```
df = data.frame(var1 = c("1","2","3","4"),var2 = c(1,2,3,4),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

yielding:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ var1: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4"
 $ var2: num  1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, adding the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` will create character variables instead of factor variables.